# Preloading an image to be displayed in an image gallery in Vue

Tags: image, vue.js, vuejs2, preload

I'm writing in Vue with Typescript

Currently, I am building a image gallery, and when a button is selected, a corresponding image appears. I to do this, I wrote the following:

```html
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
  <img :src="getImage(images[selected])" :key="selected">
</transition>
```

where inside the methods I have this function

```js
getImage(imageURL: string){
  return require('@/assets/lensTreatments/' + imageURL)
}
```

and in the created hook, I have this function

```js
created(){
  this.treatmentImages.forEach(imageURL=>{
    new Image().src = this.getImage(imageURL);
  })
}
```

This does not work, as demonstrated with the network panel

[image: Network Panel]

How can I make it so that the src in the image points towards the images that I fetch in the created hook?